# ValueError: Length of new names must be 1, got 2

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, pandas-resample

I am trying to resample a time series, with reference to the start and end data in another table as below. Data is as below:
`df1:`

```
        Index   Timestamp               Data    ID
2   1   2       2014-03-04 13:16:44.310 30.0    2
    6   8       2014-03-04 13:17:01.777 30.0    2
    37  47      2014-04-17 11:59:57.470 25.0    2
```

`df2:`

```
    ID  Start Date  End Date    comment Name
8   10  2014-04-20  2014-04-30  TBA     NN95
9   2   2014-03-04  2014-03-14  TBA     AA01
116 120 2014-04-17  2014-04-27  TBA     BB10
```

Reproducible examples:
`df1:`

```
from pandas import Timestamp

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Index': {(2, 1): 2,
  (2, 6): 8,
  (2, 37): 47,
  (2, 81): 92,
  (2, 88): 101,
  (2, 132): 146,
  (2, 139): 155,
  (2, 436): 453,
  (2, 545): 564,
  (2, 816): 835,
  (10, 172): 188,
  (10, 450): 469,
  (10, 565): 584,
  (10, 830): 849,
  (10, 1000): 1019,
  (10, 271312): 271331,
  (10, 271313): 271332,
  (10, 271314): 271333,
  (10, 271315): 271334,
  (10, 271316): 271335,
  (120, 1614): 1633,
  (120, 1665): 1684,
  (120, 1666): 1685,
  (120, 1733): 1752,
  (120, 1734): 1753,
  (120, 1835): 1854,
  (120, 1836): 1855,
  (120, 1957): 1976,
  (120, 1958): 1977,
  (120, 2091): 2110},
 'Timestamp': {(2, 1): Timestamp('2014-03-04 13:16:44.310000'),
  (2, 6): Timestamp('2014-03-04 13:17:01.777000'),
  (2, 37): Timestamp('2014-04-17 11:59:57.470000'),
  (2, 81): Timestamp('2014-04-17 12:01:08.973000'),
  (2, 88): Timestamp('2014-04-17 12:05:55.153000'),
  (2, 132): Timestamp('2014-04-17 12:08:58.933000'),
  (2, 139): Timestamp('2014-04-17 12:35:58.290000'),
  (2, 436): Timestamp('2014-04-17 12:41:42.147000'),
  (2, 545): Timestamp('2014-04-17 12:46:14.450000'),
  (2, 816): Timestamp('2014-04-17 13:05:53.077000'),
  (10, 172): Timestamp('2014-04-17 12:35:58.633000'),
  (10, 450): Timestamp('2014-04-17 12:41:42.067000'),
  (10, 565): Timestamp('2014-04-17 12:46:14.747000'),
  (10, 830): Timestamp('2014-04-17 13:05:53.153000'),
  (10, 1000): Timestamp('2014-04-17 13:10:20.127000'),
  (10, 271312): Timestamp('2014-05-13 14:59:44.627000'),
  (10, 271313): Timestamp('2014-05-13 14:59:44.780000'),
  (10, 271314): Timestamp('2014-05-13 14:59:45.600000'),
  (10, 271315): Timestamp('2014-05-13 14:59:45.757000'),
  (10, 271316): Timestamp('2014-05-13 14:59:46.687000'),
  (120, 1614): Timestamp('2014-04-17 15:39:52.673000'),
  (120, 1665): Timestamp('2014-04-17 15:46:41.260000'),
  (120, 1666): Timestamp('2014-04-17 15:46:41.417000'),
  (120, 1733): Timestamp('2014-04-17 16:07:54.657000'),
  (120, 1734): Timestamp('2014-04-17 16:07:54.817000'),
  (120, 1835): Timestamp('2014-04-17 16:23:59.943000'),
  (120, 1836): Timestamp('2014-04-17 16:24:00.103000'),
  (120, 1957): Timestamp('2014-04-17 16:53:00.543000'),
  (120, 1958): Timestamp('2014-04-17 16:53:00.703000'),
  (120, 2091): Timestamp('2014-04-17 17:29:21.163000')},
 'Data': {(2, 1): 30.0,
  (2, 6): 30.0,
  (2, 37): 25.0,
  (2, 81): 25.0,
  (2, 88): 25.0,
  (2, 132): 25.0,
  (2, 139): 25.0,
  (2, 436): 25.0,
  (2, 545): 25.0,
  (2, 816): 25.0,
  (10, 172): 25.0,
  (10, 450): 25.0,
  (10, 565): 25.0,
  (10, 830): 25.0,
  (10, 1000): 25.0,
  (10, 271312): 25.0,
  (10, 271313): 27.5,
  (10, 271314): 27.5,
  (10, 271315): 30.5,
  (10, 271316): 30.5,
  (120, 1614): 31.0,
  (120, 1665): 30.5,
  (120, 1666): 30.0,
  (120, 1733): 29.5,
  (120, 1734): 29.0,
  (120, 1835): 28.5,
  (120, 1836): 28.0,
  (120, 1957): 27.5,
  (120, 1958): 27.0,
  (120, 2091): 26.5},
 'ID': {(2, 1): 2,
  (2, 6): 2,
  (2, 37): 2,
  (2, 81): 2,
  (2, 88): 2,
  (2, 132): 2,
  (2, 139): 2,
  (2, 436): 2,
  (2, 545): 2,
  (2, 816): 2,
  (10, 172): 10,
  (10, 450): 10,
  (10, 565): 10,
  (10, 830): 10,
  (10, 1000): 10,
  (10, 271312): 10,
  (10, 271313): 10,
  (10, 271314): 10,
  (10, 271315): 10,
  (10, 271316): 10,
  (120, 1614): 120,
  (120, 1665): 120,
  (120, 1666): 120,
  (120, 1733): 120,
  (120, 1734): 120,
  (120, 1835): 120,
  (120, 1836): 120,
  (120, 1957): 120,
  (120, 1958): 120,
  (120, 2091): 120}
  })
```

`df2:`

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': {8: 10, 9: 2, 116: 120},
 'Start Date': {8: Timestamp('2014-04-20 00:00:00'),
  9: Timestamp('2014-03-04 00:00:00'),
  116: Timestamp('2014-04-17 00:00:00')},
 'End Date': {8: Timestamp('2014-04-30 00:00:00'),
  9: Timestamp('2014-03-14 00:00:00'),
  116: Timestamp('2014-04-27 00:00:00')},
 'comment': {8: 'TBA', 9: 'TBA', 116: 'TBA'},
 'Name': {8: 'NN95', 9: 'AA01', 116: 'BB10'}})
```

I need to filter the time series data in `df1` based on the start and end date in `df2` by mapping the `ID`. Then I want to resample the data at 1 minute frequency between the start and end date(so each `ID` will have the same number of data points eventually). Finally, I would like to transpose the data with `pivot_table`.

I tried:

```
for i, j in df2.iterrows():
    current_id = df2.at[i, 'ID']
    start_date = df2.at[i, 'Start Date']
    end_date = df2.at[i, 'End Date']

    sub1 = df1[(df1.Timestamp >= start_date) & (df1.Timestamp <= end_date) & (df1.ID == current_id )]
    
    def f(x):
        r = pd.date_range(start=start_date, end = end_date, freq='1min')
        return x.reindex(r, method='ffill').bfill()

    sub2 = (sub1.set_index('Timestamp').groupby('ID', sort=False)['Data'].apply(f).rename_axis(['ID','Timestamp']).reset_index())

    df_sub1 = sub2.pivot_table('Data', 'ID', sub2.groupby('ID').cumcount()).add_prefix('x')
    print(df_sub1)
```

and it caught error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-27c1ac59f909> in <module>
     10         return x.reindex(r, method='ffill').bfill()
     11 
---> 12     sub2 = (sub1.set_index('Timestamp').groupby('ID', sort=False)['Data'].apply(f).rename_axis(['ID','Timestamp']).reset_index())
     13 
     14     df_sub1 = sub2.pivot_table('Data', 'ID', df_sub.groupby('ID').cumcount()).add_prefix('x')

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    307         @wraps(func)
    308         def wrapper(*args, **kwargs) -> Callable[..., Any]:
--> 309             return func(*args, **kwargs)
    310 
    311         kind = inspect.Parameter.POSITIONAL_OR_KEYWORD

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in rename_axis(self, mapper, **kwargs)
   1106             )
   1107             if non_mapper:
-> 1108                 return self._set_axis_name(mapper, axis=axis, inplace=inplace)
   1109             else:
   1110                 raise ValueError("Use `.rename` to alter labels with a mapper.")

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in _set_axis_name(self, name, axis, inplace)
   1180         """
   1181         axis = self._get_axis_number(axis)
-> 1182         idx = self._get_axis(axis).set_names(name)
   1183 
   1184         inplace = validate_bool_kwarg(inplace, "inplace")

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in set_names(self, names, level, inplace)
   1312         else:
   1313             idx = self._shallow_copy()
-> 1314         idx._set_names(names, level=level)
   1315         if not inplace:
   1316             return idx

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in _set_names(self, values, level)
   1227             raise ValueError("Names must be a list-like")
   1228         if len(values) != 1:
-> 1229             raise ValueError(f"Length of new names must be 1, got {len(values)}")
   1230 
   1231         # GH 20527

ValueError: Length of new names must be 1, got 2
```

What does the error mean? Is it saying I've used duplicate variable names? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `.rename_axis(['ID','Timestamp'])` did you checked this?

Comment: What is `df_sub` in the loop at last second line?

Comment: are you trying to rename `ID` index to `Timestamp`?

Comment: @AnuragDhadse Sorry it was a typo, should be `sub2 `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A axis name can only be one not two. So when you call this function the name should only be one not two:

```py
# this will give error
.rename_axis(['ID','Timestamp'])
```

The problem being you are using multi index which need to renamed.
This is possible solution:

```py
.rename_axis(index={'ID': 'Timestamp'})
```

Check this Pandas documentation https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html

Comment: Hi Anurag, thanks for the solution, but it doesn't seem to solve the issue, it returned `ValueError: Length of names must match number of levels in MultiIndex.`

Comment: Let me check if I can help with a better answer. Till then check the above link for documentation.

Comment: @nilsinelabore check if new answer help. and also change the next line with this `df_sub1 = sub2.pivot_table('Data', 'Timestamp', sub2.groupby('Timestamp').cumcount()).add_prefix('x')` . If that's what you intending to do?

Comment: Unfortunately it caught error `KeyError: 'ID'`

Comment: update last line of loop, `ID` with `Timestamp`